# Dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary,

```
dict={"1":"2" , "2":"4"}
```

Is it possible to create another dictionary that has, as values, lists of the values of the first dictionary?

For example in this case the output is

```
dictionary={"1":["4","2"],"2":["4"]}
```

because in the first dict "1" is key of "2" that at the same time is key of "4". So we have in the new dictionary.

```
"1":["4","2"]
```

While `"2"` is key of `4`, that is not a key of another value.

How can I implement this?

Comment: How have you *tried* to write it, and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: This question is a little confusing, because you appear to be using string and numeric values interchangeably (a number with quotes around it is a string). In this case, it won't dramatically affect the answer, buy you should decide whether you want `1` or `"1"`, and ask for that, specifically.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have you tried using recursion?

Comment: I there a reason you want `[4 , 2]` instead of `[2, 4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad question, so I'll only give you a jumping off point.

```
dict1={"1":"2" , "2":"4", "4": "3"}

def list_maker(dictionary, key, list):
    if key not in dictionary:
        return [key] + list[:-1]
    else:
        return list_maker(dictionary, dictionary[key], [key] + list)

print(list_maker(dict1, "1", []))
```

See what that gives you and work from there

Comment: Why are you removing the last element of the list? Also, checking to see whether the key is in the list would avoid infinite loops. It seems to me that this could be done with a while loop. Wouldn't that be more efficient?

Comment: I remove the last element of the list because it was the original "key" argument, and should not appear in the list. I'm pretty sure it would be possible with a while loop quite easily.  I used recursion because that was most obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> dict1={"1":"2" , "2":"4"}
>>> for i in dict1.keys():
    appendvalue=[dict1.get(i)]
    if dict1.get(i) in dict1.keys():
        appendvalue.append(dict1.get(dict1.get(i)))
    dict1[i]=appendvalue


>>> dict1
{'1': ['2', '4'], '2': ['4']}
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more than two keys and values chained

Comment: Can you give example ? for `{"1":"2" , "2":"4", "4":"5" , "5":"6"}` it worked

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, for the example you give the output should be `{'1': ['6', '5', '4', '2'], '2': ['6', '5', '4'], '4': ['6', '5'], '5': ['6']}` and not `{'1': ['2', '4'], '2': ['4', '5'], '4': ['5', '6'], '5': ['6']}`. I could be wrong, though. I had not considered that this may be what he is asking

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
dict={"1":"2" , "2":"4"}
final_dict={}
for index,item in dict.items():
    final_dict[index]=[item]
    if item in dict.keys():
        final_dict[index].extend([dict[item]])
print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'2': ['4'], '1': ['2', '4']}
```